# Is there any way to create watch on someone's activity in stackoverflow?

Tags: support, users, recent-activity

If one of my friends ask a question on Stack Overflow, how do I get an alert or notification? With this feature, I can help them to solve their issue. Currently they have to inform me by email or chat.

Comment: You shouldn't stalk people.

Comment: I think favorite feature is what you are looking for.

Comment: @EvanCarroll i don't want to stalk people. but, is it possible that if i send a request to any user and they accept it. once the user accepted the request then it should be in my watch list. but, should have right to remove their entry from another's list.

Comment: I think that's a GREAT feature request, "Do you want to be stalked?"

Comment: If I want to stalk someone then there are other approaches. Just find that user and go to activity in their profile.  But, I want to get alert from who added me in their list wherever they ask question.

Comment: @EvanCarroll Yes, it feels like stalking to me, too, but that information is available via the profile pages as of now, so why not give alerts on specific events? It does not add any new information, just lets you find specific parts of it easier.

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian I have read that 10 times then i have realize that. Such a SE is not a social networking site. But, still there is an option to chat with other user.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you go to your friend's profile page, at the bottom you'll see a link to their "user feed".  This will give you an RSS feed of your friend's activity.

[image]

Comment: I have tried this. when i have clicked on that link. it shows me a xml document. How do i use it?

Comment: You subscribe to it with an RSS reader. Do some googling about RSS feeds and how to use them.

Comment: I thought RSS was officially obsoleted on July 1, 2013.